# Firebase pure Go language based authentication | Golang

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, authentication, go, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to find a way of authenticating a user with email /password purely through Go. I'm using Go templates and would like to use HTML purely as a dumb terminal to fetch input from. I seem to need to go through the firebase-app.js apis, sign-in, then pass the returned UID to go. Am I missing something? I am looking for something similar to the js :

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(_emailText, _passText)
```

I've had no luck finding anything in the godocs.

I figured it would be straight forward since I'm hosting on GAE and fetching a firebase service account is trivial. But it seems I need to capture the userInfo through js and possibly pass it back to go possibly through a GET method.

thanks in advance!

Comment: If wanting to use Go, have you looked into https://godoc.org/firebase.google.com/go? Specifically, https://godoc.org/firebase.google.com/go/auth

Comment: Firebase Auth is intended to be used directly from the client (JS in this case). The only pure-server way I'm aware of to do this is via custom tokens, in which case you would need to store your own usernames/passwords and generate ID tokens on sign-in.

Comment: Yup, I've been through the Auth firebase godocs. It looks like @MichaelBleigh is right so I'll stick to auth() through JS for now.

Comment: Also asked on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/19-yduAoGIk