# Firebase SignInWithEmailandPassword

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-authentication

I'm creating a api with Go, and I use Firebase as database and ("firebase.google.com/go/auth") for authentication. This package has CreateUser function and I can create a user with that but when I need a signin function for authentication I couldn't find that. It's present for JavaScript as (SignInWithEmailandPassword) but not for Go. Do you know any alternative or solution?

I've tried this and it worked out successfully. But it doesn't seems like true. I think that, an authentication store should've signin function. Or easier way to do this

```
    "apiKey, err := os.ReadFile("./apikey.txt")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        url := fmt.Sprintf("https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=%s", string(apiKey))
        requestData := map[string]string{
            "email":             email,
            "password":          password,
            "returnSecureToken": "true",
        }"
```

Comment: maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54153315/firebase-pure-go-language-based-authentication-golang

Comment: "I'm creating a api with Go" You should be using [Firebase Admin SDK for Go](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-go) if its on server side.